# Why does my function not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use Ajax toolkit.I want create text editor for HTML codes. I found .css file in html link tags and for each of these files, create a LinkButton. I want when user click linkbutton .css file open in editor. I write this code:

```
string textHtml = "";
List<string> listTextHtml = new List<string>();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AsyncPostBackTrigger d = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();

    if (IsPostBack)
        return;
    StreamReader re = new StreamReader(string.Concat(Server.MapPath("/"), "\\Engine\\TextFile1.txt"));
    while (re.Peek() > 0)
    {
        txtHtmlCode.Content = txtHtmlCode.Content + re.ReadLine() + "\n";
    }
    textHtml = txtHtmlCode.Content;
    re.Close();
    string temp = textHtml;
    while (temp.Contains("link"))
    {
        string s = temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf("link"), temp.IndexOf("/>"));
        temp = temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf("/>") + 2);
        if (s.IndexOf(".css") >= 0)
        {
            s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("href=\"") + 6);
            listTextHtml.Add(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("\"") - 1));
        }
        //temp = temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf("href="));
        //temp = temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf("\"") + 1);
        //listTextHtml.Add(temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf("\"") - 1));
        //temp = temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf("\"") + 1);
    }
    int i = 0;
    hfString.Value = "";
    foreach (var item in listTextHtml)
    {
        //HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.ID = i.ToString();

        lb.Text = "Link - " + i.ToString();
        //lb.Click += ltnCssLoad_Click;
        lb.Click += new EventHandler(this.ltnCssLoad_Click);
        //li.Controls.Add(lb);
        phTags.Controls.Add(lb);
        d.ControlID = i.ToString();
        d.EventName = "Click";
        //udpMain.Triggers.Add(d);
        i++;
        hfString.Value += item + "|";
    }
}
```

when click the `linkbutton` this function must run:

```
protected void ltnCssLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton ClickedLink = (LinkButton)sender;
    string[] listText = hfString.Value.Split('|');//string.Concat(Server.MapPath("/"),
    StreamReader re = new StreamReader(string.Concat(string.Concat(Server.MapPath("/"), listText[int.Parse(ClickedLink.ID)])));
    txtHtmlCode.Content = "";
    while (re.Peek() > 0)
    {
        txtHtmlCode.Content = txtHtmlCode.Content + re.ReadLine() + "\n";
    }
    re.Close();
}
```

but when I use break point in function `ltnCssLoad_Click`, this function not work when I click in linkbutton. How can I fix this?

Comment: "Not work"? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Apparently his English is not that good, but I'm sure what he wants to mean is clear, 'my function isn't working' or 'my function doesn't work'

Comment: @MindlessRanger you're kind of stating the obvious. The question is "What doesn't work", or "Explain what you expect to see, what you actually see and what you have tried to resolve those differences". Also explained in [ask].

Comment: Excuse me.my english Language is not  good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because when you click link button or any dynamically added control it causes post back and you have "return"ed in page load event handler if IsPostBack is true.

The pain with using dynamic controls is that you have to recreate them every time (first request as well as subsequent post backs).

Restrict file reading to first request (i.e. put it in !IsPostBack condition) and let link buttons' creation code run after that.